# How to change the brightness of the mouse cursor for eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, ide

The short version is that I've turned the brightness way down on my monitor and now I'm having problems finding the mouse cursor in eclipse (the text cursor). When it's a pointer cursor it's fine, but when it goes to the text cursor I can barely see it. Half the time I'm guessing where it is.

To be quite honest this is for all of Windows, but it's really a problem for me in eclipse where I spend a lot of time.

**Update:** I have looked at the windows settings, specifically the "Text Select" under "Pointers", but I'm not sure what to replace it with. I don't know anything about the .cur file it requires.

Comment: Don't you have a folder of cursors, like e.g. [here](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-customize-mouse-cursors-windows-7)? There should be some that look like the standard text cursor, just contoured. There should be no need to manually create .cur files (which are just renamed .ico files, IIRC) just to get this cursor better visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sitting at a Windows box right now, so I can't try, but you can set the mouse cursor in the system settings / mouse settings. You can set specific cursors, like the text cursor. Windows ships (at least: shipped) with cursor themes that are much better visible. The same problem can occur when you need the "precision select" cursor - a small negative cross, invisible on grey background. But there are replacements with strong contours that are easily visible. So you don't have to change the whole pointer theme, if you don't want to, but can change just this one or two problematic.

I did this when using Windows XP, I hope it still is valid for 7.